# forEach typeorm update cause error: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

How can I deal with this scenario ? A typeOrm based PGSQL update with forEach :

```
datas.forEach(d => {
    this.entity.update(d.id, {somefields})
}
```

This cause a PostGreSQL Error :

```
error: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Tried to limit maxConnections of TypeORM to 5 but still the issue.